# Integral $\int_{-1}^{0}\dfrac{1}{x(x^2+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

Suppose I have to compute $\int_{-1}^{0}\dfrac{1}{x(x^2+1)}$. I use partial fractions to get $\int_{-1}^{0}\left(\dfrac1x-\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}\right)$, which integrates to $\log(x)-\log(x^2+1)$. Now, the $\log$ is not defined for $x\in[-1,0)$. What do I do in this case?

Comment: $$\int\frac1xdx=\log|x|\;,\;\;\text{not merely}\;\;\log x\ldots$$ Anyway your integral is not convergent...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: I would point out that your antiderivative should be
$$
\int\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)\,dx=\ln\lvert x\rvert-\frac{1}{2}\ln\lvert x^2+1\rvert+C,
$$
which takes care of the problems on $(-1,0)$. However, you still have a problem at $0$ itself.

Remember, this is an improper integral, and so you actually have to compute it as
$$
\lim_{A\rightarrow0^{-}}\int_{-1}^A\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)\,dx.
$$
Try doing it this way, and check to see whether or not the limit converges.  If it doesn't, then this integral is divergent, and you can't put a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see this is to notice that
$${1\over x(x^2 + 1)}\sim {1\over x}$$ as $x\to 0$ Since
$x\mapsto 1/x$ does not integrate at zero, we are done.